# How to Edit linq result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an query to get data and then i convert this data to a Json Object .
But i need some change after getting result to make correct data . for example i need change my "MainImageAddress" Field from X.com to XX.com.
i need a direct solution not by using Converting to datatable!

this is my code

```
var ThisArticle = (from Article in DarunamaEntity.ArticleNews
                                 where Article.IdArticleNews == ID_int
                                 select new
                                 {

                                     AID = Article.IdArticleNews,
                                     Views = Article.CountUserVisit,
                                     TextTitle = Article.TilteTextNews,
                                     MainImageAddress = Article.ImageUrlMain,
                                     Brief = Article.brief,
                                     Content = Article.BodyTextNews
                                 });

            JsonExport = serials.Serialize(ThisArticle);
```

### ---Update --

i tested this code :

```
var ThisArticle = (from Article in DarunamaEntity.ArticleNews
                                 where Article.IdArticleNews == ID_int
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     //~
                                     AID = Article.IdArticleNews,
                                     Views = Article.CountUserVisit,
                                     TextTitle = Article.TilteTextNews,
                                     MainImageAddress = convertToValidURL(Article.ImageUrlMain),
                                     //ThumbImage = Article.thumbUrl,
                                     Brief = Article.brief,
                                     Content = Article.BodyTextNews
                                 }).ToList().Select(Article=> new {
                                    AID = Article.AID,
                                    Views = Article.Views,
                                    TextTitle = Article.TextTitle,
                                    MainImageAddress = convertToValidURL(Article.MainImageAddress),
                                    Brief = Article.Brief,
                                    Content = Article.Content
                                 });

            JsonExport = serials.Serialize(ThisArticle);
```

and this is my convertToValidURL method :

```
 public static string convertToValidURL(string URLImage)
    {

        if (URLImage == "" || URLImage == null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        URLImage = URLImage.Replace("~", "");
        URLImage = "http://www.darunama.com" + URLImage;
        int MessageCount = 0;


        return URLImage;
    }
```

**but i get this error yet :**

System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String convertToValidURL(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: have you tried this? MainImageAddress = Article.ImageUrlMain=="x.com"?"xx.com":Article.ImageUrlMain; I mean you can edit your query and make this change in your query.

Comment: yes but its not aswer . i cant change it out of linq !

Comment: why did users take to my answer -4 score ?? because of what ??? i don’t know really this reason !!

Comment: Stage the results of your query locally by forcing query execution and then transform those results as desired.  You can't use custom methods in LINQ to Entity queries directly.  Please mention that is what you are using in the question next time.  The more details you provide will make it easier for others to give you correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a private method and call that inside your LINQ expression.

```
var ThisArticle = (from a in DarunamaEntity.ArticleNews where a.IdArticleNews == ID_int
                 select new  {    
                               AID = a.IdArticleNews,
                               Views = a.CountUserVisit,
                               TextTitle = a.TilteTextNews,
                               MainImageAddress =a.ImageUrlMain,
                               Brief = a.brief,
                               Content = a.BodyTextNews
                             })
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(x=> new YourDto
                             {
                               AID = x.IdArticleNews,
                               MainImageAddress = TransformToWhatyouWant(x.ImageUrlMain)
                              // Fill in the remaining properties as well
                              }).ToList();
```

Add this method to the same class

```
public string TransformToWhatyouWant(string imageUrlMain)
{
  //do what you want to do and return the updated string
  return "update your string and return here"; 
}
```

Comment: Yes of cource but i get this error: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method &#39;System.String convertToValidURL(System.String)&#39; method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @Mohammad See the updated answer. Replace YourDto with your DTO/POCO/VIEW MODEL  class name

Answer (score 0):

```
var ThisArticle = (from Article in DarunamaEntity.ArticleNews
    where Article.IdArticleNews == ID_int
    select new
    {
        AID = Article.IdArticleNews,
        Views = Article.CountUserVisit,
        TextTitle = Article.TilteTextNews,
        MainImageAddress = Article.ImageUrlMain,
        Brief = Article.brief,
        Content = Article.BodyTextNews
    })
    .ToList()  // Convert from LINQ over SQL to LINQ over Objects
    .Select(Article=> new {
        AID = Article.IdArticleNews,
        Views = Article.CountUserVisit,
        TextTitle = Article.TilteTextNews,
        MainImageAddress = TransformThis(Article.ImageUrlMain),
        Brief = Article.brief,
        Content = Article.BodyTextNews
    });

JsonExport = serials.Serialize(ThisArticle);
```

Comment: Not fixed yet my friend, i describe this in my main Comment whit details... plz see it in top of page

Comment: @Mohammad Change `MainImageAddress = convertToValidURL(Article.ImageUrlMain),` to just `MainImageAddress = Article.ImageUrlMain,` in your attempt.  You'll notice my answer doesn't have that.  The conversion only goes in the second part of the query, not the first.